# How to call a url every 5 minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, scheduled-tasks

I'm used to Cronjobs in PHP... Set up a cronjob that goes to a url every x minutes.

However, in ASP .Net C# and I guess also down to Microsoft Azure, I cannot find a simple way of calling a URL on a scheduled timer?

What's the way you go about this?

I would like something like this:

```
every 5 minutes, please invoke this url: www.example.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the Azure Scheduler Service.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

In particular, I believe this tutorial is exactly what you want.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/scheduler-get-started-portal/

Comment: ah i see that there seems to be some missing options regarding do get requests etc as explained in these videos... in my azure account.. that's probably why it seems so complex.

Comment: It's asking for a job file?

Comment: The videos are ok. But, look at the tutorial that I just added to the answer. I believe that is exactly what you want, which is, just invoke an HTTP GET operation.

Comment: Thank you! Was hidden away to be honest! nice one dude!